# Access load-balanced website when DNS lookup is restricted on server

Tags: security, dns, server, windows-firewall

The scenario is - I need to send push notification to Apple push server hosted at `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`. This Apple server is load balanced and the destination IP address can be anything in 17.x.x.x block.

Now my server which will be requesting Apple server is in secure environment and is behind firewalls. I have got the IP range 17.x.x.x unblocked, but DNS resolving is not possible on that server. That server also doesn't have Internet access on it.

What I did was - I pinged the Apple server from another system and got the Apple server's IP address for the moment. Then I mapped that IP address with the DNS name in the hosts file of my Windows server. This worked, but now the IP address can change anytime at the Apple end, and this will break things.

What can I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can talk to your security people and in cooperation with them come up with a proper, internally supported, way to provide what you need. What  you need is to look up an address, and then talk to that address. Currently, you are only provided half of that.

What you're asking us for is a way to circumvent your own organization's security policies (policies that admittedly appear stupid, but that's another matter entirely). Even if someone here can come up with a technical way to do what you ask that works for now, it's likely to break at any time, since you're working at odds with your own workplace. Also, what will your bosses say if they find out that you're violating security policies?

Security very often comes down to tradeoffs. As the saying goes, the only truly secure system is one that has been encased in concrete and sunk to the bottom of the sea. But such a system will also be somewhat difficult to get useful work out of, so usually we accept lesser security in order to get work done. In your case, the tradeoff currently sits in a place that prevents you from doing whatever it is you're working on. So your organization needs to make a choice: change the tradeoff so that your machine can look up names, or keep the current tradeoff and accept that your task will not be done.

I'm sorry that I can't give you a straight up "Sure, do this" kind of answer, but your problem really is not technical.